# Cast identical methods from different modules in Java

Tags: java, methods, import, module, casting

My java program works with a method of an external class that I cannot modify. This method takes an object of the class *com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType*. The module *com.name.xx.yyy* is also included externally in my program.

I also have a ResultType class in my program. The attributes of this class are exactly the same as the attributes from the *com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType* class. The only exception is that I use lists instead of arrays in the classes of my program.

Is casting using **com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType.class.cast(resultType)** possible here ?  Will the lists be automatically converted to arrays in this case?

```
Util.doSomething(com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType.class.cast(resultType));
```

Or is it necessary to write a separate method for each of my classes, as you can see here ?

```
public com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType cast(ResultType resultType) {
    
    com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType casted = new com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType();

    // A list of VResultType objects is transformed into an array
    casted.setVResults(resultType.getVResults().toArray(new com.name.xx.yyy.VResultType[0])); 
    
    // A string is passed
    casted.setHostCode(resultType.getHostCode()); 
    
    // a cast must also be implemented for this subobject
    // casted.setCode(resultType.getCode()); 
    
    
    return cast;
    
}
```

Would it help if the lists in my classes were also arrays? Would it then be possible to safely cast my object using **com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType.class.cast(resultType)** and pass it to the external class method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The cast is not possible since the two classes are unrelated (none of them extends the other). But you could probably make your `ResultType` extend `com.name.xx.yyy.ResultType`. In this case the cast will be possible (though unnecessary)

Comment: Casting does not automatically convert one type of object into another type of object, so casting is not the solution. You'll need to write some code that copies and converts the fields of one object into the other.